# Synchronize flex states with bison (HTTP parser)

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to write a HTTP parser using flex bison. My first thought was to lex only the most basic tokens and use the parser to combine them. For example in the HTTP header there would be tokens like `GET`, `POST` or `PUT` as well as `URL` and `HTTP_VERSION`. The problem now is, that it is perfectly valid for a URL to include e.g. the string `"POST"` and the lexer can not differentiate between the `"POST"` in an `URL` token or the `"POST"` in an actual `POST` token.

A solution to that problem would be to use flex *start condition states*, to enable and disable specific patterns dependent on what is expected. After finding a `GET`, `POST`, etc. token in the `INITIAL` state, the lexer switches to another state where it only matches the `URL`. This solution does not feel right though. It feels like implementing logic in the lexer that belongs into the parser (stuff like "there is exactly one `GET`, `POST`,... token followed by exactly one `URL`).

That brings me to my question:
Is there a way to "synchronize" between a bison parser and a flex lexer, so that I can change the lexer state depending on what bison expects to be the next token?

P.S.:
I don't know much about grammar classes and theoretical stuff behind parsing languages. It feels to me that parsing a HTTP header does not even require a contex free language parser like bison. Is HTTP a regular language, so that I can parse it with a regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is a regular language. We can see that from the fact, that it can be parsed with a finite state machine. In theory it should be possible (don't quote me on that) to match an entire HTTP message with a regular expression. The problem with this parsing approach is, that common regex languages don't have sofisticated capture options. Often we can capture single submatches and store them for later use, but there is no such thing like the callback-like approach in bison, where one can specify arbitrary actions based on the recognition of some subpattern.

The reason that bison and flex are not the right tools for this problem (as stated in other answers) lays in a very fundamental property that distuingishes the HTTP language from typical programming languages, where flex and bison are usually used:

A programming language consists of an alphabet of tokens. That means e.g. a keyword can be thought of a single element in that alphabet and the input stream of characters can unambiguously be converted into a stream of tokens. This is exactly the purpose of the lexer, which kind of acts as a translator from one alphabet to another. There are situations where the lexer additionally acts as parser and requires more internal logic, than simply translating input sequences to tokens. One of the most common of these situations are comments. A keyword in a comment no longer emits a token.

For HTTP on the other hand, the alphabet is just the input characters. It makes not much sense to use a lexer. The problem that the OP mentioned about the communication between flex and bison stems from the fact, that he tried to split the parsing of the language (which is a single problem) in two parts. Flex is **not** a parser and not suitable for parsing. The solution would be to just ignore the lexer stage, as it is not needed. Bison is very capable of producing a parser for a regular language and can be used to parse HTTP.

That brings me to the last point. Even if bison is capable of generating a regular language parser, it is not the most suitable tool. Bison can generate parser for context-free languages. Those are parsed using a finite state machine with a stack. For parsing a regular language, one does not need the stack, as there are no nested structures, that need to be "remembered". Thus most likely a HTTP parser generated by bison will not be as optimized as a parser generated by a regular language parser generator. Sadly, I could not find a pure regular language parser generator, but such a thing would be the preferrable tool to generate a HTTP parser.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bison to parse a HTTP header is not just overkill; it's a mismatch between tool and problem. It's like trying to write an essay using Photoshop. Photoshop is a highly sophisticated tool which, in the hands of a skilled operator, can make any image look beautiful, and in a certain sense, an essay is an image (or a series of images). But the task is ridiculous. Sure, Photoshop has text blocks. But you don't want to concentrate on every rectangular block of text. You want to write, letting the words flow from page to page, something which is outside of Photoshop's model, regardless of how sophisticated the tool is.

Bison and Flex are designed to parse a language with a complex syntax, in which the input can first be separated into lexical units (tokens) without regard to their syntactic context. If you find yourself asking questions like "how can I communicate the nature of the expected input to the lexer?", then you are probably using the wrong tool. Certainly, Flex is a powerful tool and it has features which let it adapt to minor variations in the lexical context. But these should be exceptional cases.

Protocols like HTTP are designed to be easy to analyse. You need neither a parser nor a lexer to see which of a handful of possible verbs is at the start of a line, or to extract the following string up to the first space character. You don't need to do sophisticated error analysis and recovery, and you shouldn't even try because it will leak information and could open a vulnerability. If a character can't be parsed, just send a 400 and stop reading.

Good tools simplify the solution of problems within the domain fir which they were designed. Part of the skillset of a good engineer is recognising which tools are appropriate to a given problem. In this case, Bison/Flex is not the tool.

And I'm not sure that regular expressions help much either, because the main challenge in HTTP parsing is dealing with an input stream which is intermittent, asynchronous, somewhat unreliable, and subject to attack. Like Flex, most regex libraries expect a single input string, already clearly terminated, which is not the case for a protocol transmitted over the internet.

It is possible to construct a backchannel from a Bison parser to a Flex scanner, but this is not the place to try it. So I'm disinclined to try to explain the techniques within this context.

Comment: Writing an HTTP parser that handles all the cornercases of the protocol and strictly adheres to the standard should in my opinion be done with a parser/lexer generator. Even the [HTTP standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-2.1) itself is defined using an augmented Backus-Naur Form. Splitting a parser's language definition from the actual implementation makes the code easier to read and easier to extend (at least in my opinion). Anyway could you at least provide me a keyword or a link to where I can read more about this "backchannel" that you mentioned.

Comment: @Jakob: You already know the nature of the backchannel; it involves using Flex's start conditions. Generally, one adds exported functions to the flex file which change lexer state, since the BEGIN macro and the state names are not exported in any header. The problem, as you also seem to know, is that lexical analysis and parsing are not very well synchronised, and there is no reliable mechanism to force synchronisation. However, you do have the option of placing a mid-rule action either before or after the token which comes before the desired state change; usually one of these positions...

Comment: ... is correctly synchronised. This can be verified by examining the value of `yych` at runtime, but that's not ideal. It can also be derived by examining bison's state transition table, which can be generated in human-readable (and some other) formats by the `-v` option. Personally, I think constructing Rube Goldbergs of this form does not satisfy the goal of producing code which is easier to read, extend and verify. A more appropriate parsing framework for HTTP (and most other comms protocols) is predictive parsing (aka recursive descent, although there is no recursion necessary here)...

Comment: since a predictive parser doesn't call the lexer until it knows the range of possible responses, it is a much more natural framework for inputs which don't naturally allow non-contextual lexical analysis. Good luck with your project.

Comment: thanks a lot for the information. I will look into it.